# Adding depth to a 2D rotated element

Tags: css, rotation, css-transforms

In essence, I need to have my `div` transformed to position itself like the top side of this box (ignoring the radius border, logo, gradient, etc.)

[image]

In order to do so, I need to

1. **Rotate the element** to the proper angle, which I know how to do using `transform:rotate(45deg)`. [**Example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/ELyTU/1/). The problem with this is that there is no depth, it just looks like a rotated square because that's what it is. I want it to look like a plane that something could be set on
2. **Add the perception of depth** on the element, which I also know how to do using [Craig Buckler's approach](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-starwars-scrolling-text/). [**Example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/ELyTU/2/)
3. **Combine the two effects on the element at the same time**. This is the part that I cannot seem to get correct

My basic code

```
/* HTML */
<div id='square'></div>

/* CSS (without any transforms) */
#square {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background:black;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%; left:50%;
    margin-left:-75px;
    margin-top:-75px;
}
```

I thought I could get the effect I'm looking for by simply combining the two, using

```
transform: rotate(45deg) perspective(300px) rotateX(25deg);
```

but I found it was not so. [**Example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/ELyTU/3/). The problem with this one is that it still does the `rotateX` based on the original orientation of the element, not the rotated version. Thus, it does not have the proper effect

I thought I could make it take the rotated angle of `45deg` into consideration for the `rotateX` if I applied the `rotate(45deg)` to a container element, but this was also to no avail. [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/ELyTU/)

I have tried variations of these approaches but (of course) have yet to get the effect I'm looking for

Do you have any idea how I can properly achieve this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct transform is

```
perspective(300px) rotateX(25deg) rotate(45deg);
```

You want the plane where the element is to be always facing you, so first of all you rotate in X. This sets a plane that at the bottom is near you and at the top is far from you, and you don't want this plane to rotate, so you can't place a rotation **before** it.

Once you have set this plane, then, inside it, you rotate the div.

Maybe this <kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ELyTU/4/)</kbd> makes it more clear, hover the div to see the rotation plane.

Comment: Could you also explain why this is so?

Comment: Any idea how to make the pseudo-elements [here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/uumwqeh0) look like [the ones here](http://25.media.tumblr.com/f248d102bc58a4f96afc8fe5cff16598/tumblr_mrh05oJbra1qdyzdoo1_1280.jpg)? I need to translate it along the Z but it keeps scaling it when I don't want it to (don't worry about the color, I know how to do that thanks to your background trick)

Comment: The bad news is that you need preserve-3d for the Z transform to work; and looks like any browser supports that on pseudo elements. I have redone everything in 2d: http://jsfiddle.net/vals/8hw8B/

Comment: I see. I will try to do my original intentionusing this method instead and update you with how it goes. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: If you really want to do it in 3D, then it should be done with separate (and nested) divs. (3 divs per face). Good luck !

Comment: I originally had it that way but was trying to do it with fewer elements (as always)

Comment: I was able to create the effect I desired using your approach (: [Check it out](http://codepen.io/Zeaklous/details/xawps)

Comment: Interesting (: Not exactly how I pictured it being used but that's a good thing! You should post things like that on CodePen (mostly so I can see them :P )

Comment: If you're interested, I will likely post to [this chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45741/room-for-zach-saucier-and-vals) concerning things I'm working on